# Application of binomial formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let $0<p<1$ and $n$ integer. Then

$$
\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}=(n-1)p
$$

---

Proof: By the binomial formula

$$
(p+q)^{n-1}=\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{d}p^d q^{n-1-d}
$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $p$ and replacing $q=1-p$ we get
$$
(n-1)(p+1-p)^{n-2}=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{d}p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}
$$

and the result follows.

---

Question: let's consider the example with $n=3$, $p=0.3$. Then
$$
\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}= 0.7^2+(2*0.3*0.7)+(0.3^2)=1
$$
and 
$$
(n-1)p=2*0.3=0.6
$$

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You differentiated wrong.  If you differentiate $p^d$ with respect to $p$ you should get $d\; p^{d-1}$, not just $p^{d-1}$.
The binomial theorem should give you
$$ \sum_{d=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d} = 1$$
not $(n-1)p$.  Perhaps you meant

$$ \sum_{d=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose d} d \; p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d} = (n-1) p $$